# Change an event's field using the aggregate filter in Logstash

Tags: aggregate, logstash, elastic-stack

For some days now I am struggling with a problem.

I have logs that contain the actions of the users and are of the format:

For example:

07/04/2016 00:05:57.821 reqId:1 Request Begin message body

07/04/2016 00:06:57.821 reqId:1 Request End message body

07/04/2016 00:15:57.821 reqId:2 Request Begin message body

07/04/2016 01:35:57.821 reqId:3 Request Begin message body

The request ID which is unique for each action.

Each action begins with "Request Begin" and ends with "Request End". However, there are some actions that never end (maybe due to a Java error), that is, there will not be a matching "Request End" for a specific request ID.

Using Logstash I would like to correlate the events that contain "Request Begin" with their matching "Request End" and then, using Kibana I want to retrieve all actions that do NOT contain a matching "Request End" (that is the unfinished ones.

I came across the aggregate filter. But I can not figure out how to configure it to correlate the events.

A snippet of my logstash.conf is the following:

```
if [request-status] == "Request Begin"{
            aggregate {
                task_id => "%{request-ID}"
                code => "map['request-complete']; event['request-complete']=0"
                map_action => "create_or_update"
                }
    }
    if [request-status] == "Request End"{
            aggregate {
                task_id => "%{request-ID}"
                code => "event ['request-complete'] = 1"
                map_action => "update"
                timeout => 600
                end_of_task => true
                      }
    }
```

The output is :

```
Logstash startup completed
{
             "message" => "07/04/2016 00:05:57.821 reqId:1 Request Begin message body",
            "@version" => "1",
          "@timestamp" => "2016-04-22T11:44:53.102Z",
      "real-timestamp" => "07/04/2016 00:05:57.821",
          "request-ID" => "1",
      "request-status" => "Request Begin",
        "message-body" => "message body",
    "request-complete" => 0
}
{
             "message" => "07/04/2016 00:06:57.821 reqId:1 Request End message body",
            "@version" => "1",
          "@timestamp" => "2016-04-22T11:44:53.400Z",
      "real-timestamp" => "07/04/2016 00:06:57.821",
          "request-ID" => "1",
      "request-status" => "Request End",
        "message-body" => "message body",
    "request-complete" => 1
}
{
             "message" => "07/04/2016 00:15:57.821 reqId:2 Request Begin message body",
            "@version" => "1",
          "@timestamp" => "2016-04-22T11:44:53.400Z",
      "real-timestamp" => "07/04/2016 00:15:57.821",
          "request-ID" => "2",
      "request-status" => "Request Begin",
        "message-body" => "message body",
    "request-complete" => 0
}
{
             "message" => "07/04/2016 01:35:57.821 reqId:3 Request Begin message body",
            "@version" => "1",
          "@timestamp" => "2016-04-22T11:44:53.401Z",
      "real-timestamp" => "07/04/2016 01:35:57.821",
          "request-ID" => "3",
      "request-status" => "Request Begin",
        "message-body" => "message body",
    "request-complete" => 0
}
```

**My question:**

Is there any way I can change the field "request-complete" of a "Request Begin" action to match the one of its corresponding "Request End"?

For example I would like to change the "request-complete" of the event with "request-ID => 1" and "request-status => Request Begin", from "request-complete => 0" to "request-complete => 1" (which is the same value as the event with "request-ID => 1" and "request-status => Request End").

This way I can search ,in Kibana, the events that have "request-status =Request Begin" AND "request-complete =1" (which will be all events without a matching closing event).

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I found a workaround to my problem using the elapsed filter and adding "periodic_flush => true". 
If someone has the answer (or a tip) for my problem please post it. I would love to see if I can achieve the functionality with the aggregate filter

Comment: elapsed i a good solution for this.